# Code Snippet Managers for Linux desktops?

Tags: linux, code-snippets

In the spirit of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349990/code-snippet-managers-for-os-x

What are some good code snippet managers for Linux?

My quick search didn't turn up much. Eclipse, emacs, vim, Kate, and KDevelop all offer their own integrated snippet managers, but I'm looking for something more generic along the lines of [CodeCollector](http://www.mcubedsw.com/software/codecollectorpro) or [Snippets](http://www.snippetsapp.com), ideally with the option of a CLI interface.

Even a pure CLI tool would be acceptable (maybe even preferable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen jCodeCollector? It's a significantly less complicated clone of CodeCollector, but is multiplatform (java). It is available from https://github.com/alessandrococco/jcodecollector

There is also Acire, a project started by Jono Bacon of Ubuntu fame, which is management library for useful python snippets. While full of useful tidbits, it is however, language and linux-specific.

Comment: jCodeCollector is a far from perfect choice, but certainly seems to be the best option at the moment.

Comment: Downloading jCodeCollector...

Comment: “It is available from http://alessandrococco.altervista.org/” — “The web site has been archived”

Answer (score 0):

I use snippets on the mac.  I found a similar app (though not as beautiful...) called glipper.  It is an gnome applet that was designed as a clipboard manager.  It has a snippet collector built into it though (turn it on in plugins) that lets you save snippets forever.  It is not very well organized...but it is a very simple offering that has a simple interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for Gedit that integrates with snipplr.
[Gedit Snipplr Plugin](http://www.ardeenelinfierno.com/wordpress/code/gedit-snipplr-plugin/)