# Best way to manage code snippets in Linux?

Tags: linux, code-snippets

How you manage/organize your collection of code snippets on Linux? Is there a specialized tool to do that (both in GUI and CLI environment)? Is there any convention about code snippet management in Linux? Also, I often do some work via ssh so it would be really helpful if I can access my snippet easily from command line. I just moved to Linux for several months and still got to learn a lot about software development in Linux.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: like subversion or something?

Comment: Actually like the one in visual studio

Comment: What in Visual Studio do you like? Source Safe?

Comment: [Earlier version with nearly the same title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442774/code-snippet-managers-for-linux-desktops), and I'm sure there was a very popular version of the general version of this question early on.

Comment: But what about cli? Is there no easy way to do that in cli?

Comment: @arifwn: I use emacs and the filesystem and a VCS.

Comment: Ah, emacs... I guess I should start learning to use it now. I was hoping to use some simpler software in cli but it seem none available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: [Snippely](http://code.google.com/p/snippely/) and [jCodeCollector](http://alessandro-cocco.blogspot.com/p/jcodecollector_22.html)

I use Snippely on my mac, it awesome.

**Update**: Moved to Dash for mac: http://kapeli.com/dash

Comment: Trying both now. jCodeCollector has syntax highlighting while Snippely has a nice look.

Comment: The app seems long dead, but I've been looking for hours for a Linux snippet manager and can't find ***nothing*** similar. Here the download links for 3 OS's: http://pastebin.com/TGewkQv3

Comment: It's on github: https://github.com/alessandrococco/jcodecollector. I have recently moved to Dash: http://kapeli.com/dash

Comment: Looks zuper-pro, funny that there's almost no options for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Code Barrel](http://www.codebarrel.com) to do that. For GUI based you could use the webapp but for CLI you could write scripts using the API. There is a plugin for Eclipse based IDEs as well.